# Google services slow in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, performance, youtube, google-search, google-maps

Since at least 2019/07/10, on 3 different Windows 10 PCs (mix of v1809 and v1903) used by 2 different users, we're experiencing a problem whereby seemingly all Google services (Google Maps, YouTube, Google Search, etc) load **incredibly** slowly in Google Chrome.

For example, in Google Chrome, it took 97 seconds to fully load Google Maps and ~75 seconds to fully load https://www.youtube.com/ and videos play at ~1000 Kbps.

In my testing, I have discovered the following:

- In Microsoft Edge, ironically, the exact same services work absolutely fine on the exact same network and devices at the exact same time. The videos play at 5000+ Kbps.
- Using incognito or guest modes without any extensions doesn't effect the problem.
- Updating to the latest version of Google Chrome (v76.0.3809.100) doesn't effect the problem.
- Using a different network / Internet connection doesn't effect the problem.
- Uninstalling Google Chrome, `.OLD`-ing `%localAppData%\Google\`, and reinstalling did mostly fix the problem but only for a few days then it recurred.

According to https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/google-chrome-74-75-slow-connection-on-youtube.3502325/, it seems that we're not the only ones experiencing this problem.

**Update 2019/08/14 11:35:**

I have run some benchmark / performance tests:

- Basemark Web 3.0:

  - Google Chrome: 669.85. https://web.basemark.com/result/?RZ7AyIG
  - Microsoft Edge: 288.61. https://web.basemark.com/result/?4RfA397R
- Speedtest.net:

  - Google Chrome: 13ms latency, 42.42 Mbps download, 17.80 Mbps upload
  - Microsoft Edge: 11ms latency, 42.43 Mbps download, 17.69 Mbps upload

**Update 2019/08/14 12:04:**

As recommended by https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/6lqgkl/youtube_is_only_slow_on_chrome_firefox_and_edge/, disabling chrome://flags/#enable-quic seems to have resolved the problem but I'm still confirming.

Comment: clearing/deleting cookies may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, disabling QUIC via chrome://flags/#enable-quic has resolved this problem on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised there's not more about this online. I've been experiencing this issue on and off for the last couple of months.

I just checked my `chrome://flags/#enable-quic` setting and it was already disabled! I must have done it already before but forgotten.

Anyway, I'm still here, so it obviously hasn't fixed the issue, at least not all of the time, as it occasionally and very annoyingly comes back seemingly randomly.